# Why do we witness a return to strong traditional gender norms in Western societies today?

Tags: capitalism, nationalism

Why do we witness a return to strong traditional gender norms in Western societies today?

Indeed, for women, it is translated in the interest for the figure of the witch. See the representative (best-seller) book of Mona Chollet *Sorcières* (2018) for an example. See this very good [article](https://www.marianne.net/agora/tribunes-libres/pourquoi-les-femmes-sont-elles-autant-a-ceder-a-lesoterisme) (by Louise El Yafi) in the newspaper “Marianne” for a summary of the situation in France.

For men it is the virilist movement, with a figure like Andrew Tate in the UK as an example. See this [article](https://www.ledevoir.com/societe/796243/societe-des-influenceurs-quebecois-pronent-un-nouveau-mouvement-masculin) in “Le Devoir” for a summary of the situation in Quebec, Canada.

I wonder if it is not related all in all to a new wave of anti-Enlightenment (more [anti-capitalism and anti-progress](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecofeminism) for the “witches” and more [romantic-nationalist](https://www.davispoliticalreview.com/article/andrew-tate-conservatism-and-the-death-of-masculinity?format=amp) for the “virilists”).

It coincides with inter-connected historical and political events which started from 2008 or so:

_a rise of the far-left (radical environmentalism, anarchism, etc.) and conservatism and far-right, which, for the former and the latter, adhere to the idea of a near-future collapse of the industrial societies, belief which itself self-justifies the adherence to pre-Industrial Revolution norms and values.

_a post 2008 Lehman crisis which destabilized the West

_a post 2008 which saw the re-affirmation of powers like Russia, China and India.

Comment: I'd question the assumption. A return from when? Has there actually been a regressive shift relative to the 1970s? Or the 1930s?  Haven't "Andrew Tates" always existed? The Far Left has certainly existed since at least the middle of the 1800s.

Comment: @JamesK sure, you are correct. But everything is a matter of proportion. So the point is that this movement takes a significantly large proportion today compared to the 1990s and 2000s.

Comment: I'd be willing to descrivbe the situtation as a degradation, particularly in the US [in legal terms on abortion]. But that's not even the example you gave. Andrew Tate moved from the UK to Romania to do his thing.  Romania is at the eastern fringe of the Western world. Their attitudes are surely less Western in some regards. Besides, a lot of what Tate did relied on pure economic exploitation of the poorer women there. The fact that the authorities did eventually bring a case against him suggest that one some level they are trying to Westernize rather than move in the opposite direction.

Comment: How on God's green earth can one make such a blanket statement?  Gender roles are under almost unprecedented rate of change for the last 10-15 years in Western societies.  That change is too slow for some, a cause for existential angst for others.   Did you miss the pronouns shift?  Or, highly-gendered languages like French or German adjusting?  Tate is, to put it bluntly, an internet-enabled pimp, appealing to misfits, hardly a role model for anything.  I strongly support the right of people to decide on their sexuality but this Q is not only asking for opinions, it is full of it.

Comment: If there's some kind of correlation, it's between the rise of populist right-wing movements [after 2008] and some "traditional" approach to women But even this varies by country a fair bit. I don't have the patience to read the long French article you've linked, but IIRC Le Pen is less inclined towards that than some Trump supporters.

Comment: And, yes, within art and entertainment, you can expect to be seeing some pieces appealing to traditional gender roles.  Just like others will do the opposite.  Done tastefully and with respect, why the heck not?  Art, well-done, has always been about diversity, pushing boundaries and counter-culture.

Comment: It might be better to ask more specifically about the popularity of specific individuals like Andrew Tate or specific ideologies, because "traditional gender norms" is almost meaningless depending on what tradition/era (rural societies where men and women worked in the fields? pre-industrialisation? 19th century England when many women worked in factories or domestic service? 1940s wartime? 1950s wives, which was arguably a particular moment of constructed gender difference rather than a tradition? Pre-Christian matriarchal religion?)

Comment: How is "the witch" a traditional gender role? Afaik it's such a feminist icon precisely because it was NOT a traditional gender role, but rather an expression of an independent woman that was perceived as powerful to the point of being feared for their skills not for their social bonds. Which is very different from the traditional role model of a stay-at-home-mom. Whether the esoteric part is necessarily productive is questionable, but if that is traditional then the tradition that you compare it to is very new.

Comment: And I mean the obvious answer to the increase in environmental activism and the decline in trust in the industrialism are probably linked to the ever increasing relevance of climate change, I mean it's known for a long time, but within the last decades the effects can no longer be neglected. Also sure 9/11 and the Lehman crisis might have taken a hit at the aura of invulnerability and success that the U.S. might have had. And China and India have more than a billion people that now have access to the internet, what do you expect?

Comment: Is this a question or a poorly disguised political rant?

Comment: Dude, you seem out it. You're talking about witches? And yes yes something something happened in 2008, I think everyone noticed that by 2016. That something was the rise of the internet and social media. As far as traditional gender roles go that's a backlash from the feminist side. And Andrew Tate and the ongoing controversies he's associated with, you're talking about a backlash to a backlash so you're completely missing the twist and turns of the development.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
>
> Why do we witness a return to strong traditional gender norms in Western societies today?

"Western societies" is too broad.  Western societies are not in lock step politically on social norms.  I will attempt to answer this question for the United States.

> Why do we witness a return to strong traditional gender norms in Western societies today?

Any change always faces pressure to change back by some segments of society.  The U.S. has faced some amazing changes in the last few decades.  Opposition to some of those changes including gender norms is being coalesced into political issues to drive political support ahead of an important election cycle.  This is the way the U.S political system works.  Both parties seek out issues to empower their side.

The culture wars, Family values are terms it's given in the U.S.  We are yet witnessing a return to anything.   We in the U.S. are witnessing political figures trying to create support, by testing out issues ahead of an election cycle.  One of those issues is gender norms.  They are doing so pragmatically to see how / if they resonate with the people.  Gender norms, certainly resonate with people on both sides of the issue, which means it's not really an ideal issue for politicians.   Good issues are those that resonate, empower one side but not the other.

I would say based on the interim election results in 2022,  the ballot initiatives in Kansas, Kentucky, and Ohio on 2023,  the support for the culture warriors has seemed to unite some rather large and angry crowds on the opposite side of many issues they've been vetting.  So we wait for Nov 2024 to see who wins.